# Why do these two code snippets produce different results? (Float, Double precision)

Tags: c++, floating-point, double, precision

I am only beginning to learn C++ and have been messing around with float and double values.  Below are two code snippets that seem to me to be doing the same thing but give different results.  What am I missing? Can someone explain the precision error the first code must have to get a different result than the second.

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    const float f = 0.1;
    const double d = 0.1;
    int counter = 0;

    for(counter; ((double)counter * f - (double)counter * d) < 0.34; counter++) {}

    cout << "Iterations = " << counter << "\n" ;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}


int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    float time_f = 0.1;    
    double time_d = 0.1;
    float total_f = 0;
    double total_d = 0;
    int count=0;
    double difference = 0;
    while (true) {
        total_d = count * time_d;
        total_f = count * time_f;
        if(total_f - total_d >= 0.34){

            break;
        }
        count++;

    }
    std::cout <<  count << "\n";
    system("pause");
}
```

I have altered the cast of my for loop condition between float and double but the value does not differ.

Comment: Suggested reading: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `float` and `double` have a finite representation, which means they
take on a series of descrete values, and not just any real value.  In
particular, in your example, `0.1` has no exact floating point
representation on any modern machine I know of (all of which use a base
which is a power of 2 in their implementation—`0.1` is `1/5 *
1/2`, and nothing which is a multiple of `1/5` can have a finite
representation unless the base is a multiple of 5).

The result is that either `float` and `double` have the same underlying
representation (not usually the case), or there will be a difference as 
soon as `count` is different from 0.

The usual reference for this subject is
“What
Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point
Arithmetic”.  Until you've read and understood (or at least
understood the implications) it, you shouldn't touch machine floating
point.

Answer (score 1):

Difference between that two code snippets is in cast. `counter * f` is casted to double in first snippet and stored to float variable in second one.

Here's an example of how it could look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    const float f = 0.1;
    const double d = 0.1;
    int count = 0;

    for(count; (double)(count * f) - (double)(count * d) < 0.34; count++);

    printf("Iterations = %d\n", count);
    count = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        double total_d = count * d; // is equal to (double)(count * d)
        double total_f = count * f; // is equal to (double)(count * f)
        if (total_f - total_d >= 0.34)
            break;
        count++;
    }
    printf("Iterations = %d\n", count);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't casted count to double here:

```
total_d = count * time_d;
total_f = count * time_f;
```

Another thing, those loops will never end since both subtraction operands have the same value :S